# Binding scope to ng-model dynamically through json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I am trying to auto populate a form via json as below.
I expect ng-model is bind to a scope of formValue.question001. How could it be done?

```
$scope.formValue = [
    {
        _id: '001',
        text: 'text-001',
    },
    {
        _id: '002',
        text: 'text-002'
    }
]

<form name="form" ng-submit="submitForm(formValue)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in formValue">
        <input type="text" ng-model="formValue.question{{ item._id }}">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can not use `{{` in any `ng-` directive. In `ng-repeat`, every instance will have its own scope..Just `item.question` will help!

Comment: @RayonDabre so what i can do in this case if i want ng-model to be formValue.question001 without explicitly declaring this scope in controller?

Comment: Try `<input type="text" ng-model="item._id">`

Comment: @RayonDabre i need the $scope for ng-model to contains the id of the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't have property "question#" in your formValue object.
2) There is no way to interpolate evaluated expression, you give the ng-model an expression, which is not a simple string, so you can do something like ng-model="questions[item._id]" where the questions is an array living in your scope